# Show that a group $G$ is finitely generated if and only if it is a quotient of a free group on a finite set of letters

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

As stated in the title, I am working on this exercise:

> Show that a group $G$ is finitely generated if and only if it is a quotient of a free group on a finite set of letters.

I have showed $(\Rightarrow)$ as follows:

$(\Rightarrow).$ Suppose $G$ is finitely generated, and let $S=\{a_{\alpha}\}$ be the set of all the generators. Then consider  the free group on the same set of generators, denoted by $Fr(S)$. Then there exists a homomorphism $h:Fr(S)\longrightarrow G$ such that $h(a_{\alpha})=a_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$, and thus $h$ is surjective.

However, I don't know how to show the converse. Suppose $F$ is a free group on a finite set of letters $B$, and suppose $G\cong F/N$ for some $N$, then I know that this gives us an isomorphism $$\phi:F/N\longrightarrow G,$$ but what should I do to get the information of the generators of $G$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generators of $G$ are simply the images of the generators of the free group. You can see this because the homomorphism $F\to G$ is surjective; if you can get any element in the domain, the images can get any element in the codomain. In general, a quotient of a finitely generated group is finitely generated.

Notice that this need not be a minimal generating set.

Comment: why is the homomorphism surjective? More precisely, how is the homomorphism defined?

Comment: @Jacob The quotient map $F\to F/N$ is by definition surjective. That's what it means to be a quotient. By assumption, $F/N=G$, it is not simply an isomorphism.

Comment: Oh yes you are right... sorry I forgot many group theories...